# Same regular expression executed in different running time in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, performance

I am working on a project where I am heavily using regexes. The regular expressions that I am using are quite complicated and I have to set an appropriate timeout to stop the execution, so that it doesn't try to match the string for long time.

The problem is that I have noticed that running the same regular expression (compiled) on the same string is being executed with different running times, varying from 17ms to 59ms.

Do you have any idea why it is the case? I am measuring the run time using `Stopwatch` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    sw.Start();
    regex.IsMatch(message);
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Reset();
}
```

For reference I am using the default regular expressions library from .NET in `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

---

According to the comments, I modified the code in the following way:

```
List<long> results = new List<long>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
{
    sw.Start();
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++ )
    { 
        regex.IsMatch(message);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    results.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Reset();
}
Debug.WriteLine(results.Max());
Debug.WriteLine(results.Average());
Debug.WriteLine(results.Min());
```

and the output for this was:

```
790
469,086666666667
357
```

Still the difference is very significant for me.

Comment: 17ms to 59ms could easily be Window's thread scheduling. Try testing over sufficient iterations to average out that effect,=

Comment: One `regex.IsMatch(message);` may not tell you the truth. use another for loop inside that and run it many times. then compare them.

Comment: if this code is in the `main` method or in some constructor or startup method, it will not fetch the correct results. Try putting it in some place where it would start after an user interaction. the time is calculated right from the launch of the app and @Richard points out the reason why it's not accurate.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I have just tried to run it with inside loop of 20 iterations and it varied between 359 to 651ms.

Comment: It would be good to see your debug output. I don't know the inner workings of IsMatch but it could be possible that it's caching the response for said message. Is it "slow" the first time but quicker for subsequent calls? However,  I tend to agree with the first comment from @Richard

Comment: try put `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(1);` at first of your program to make your program run on single core. (for this you need to import `System.Diagnostics`) . also 20 iterations is not much.

Comment: It may be *compilation*, which´s lazy (regular expression compiles at the first call) causes the effect. Could you, please, try `Debug.WriteLine(results.Skip(1).Max());...` i.e. *skip* 1st call?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I tried it in the way you suggested and the results are much more stable, between 721-851ms (in comparison to 715-1498ms without affinity set).

Comment: so they are pretty much same. as you see other things affect performance. you processor maybe busy to do other processes. it just doesnt process your program but other programs in background affect the results. you can also add this `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;` to set the priority of your program to high. so the cpu core spends much more cycles on your program rather than other programs. but this does not mean each run should complete at exact same time.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks for help, I will definitely take it into account in further development of my project. If you make it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I think that it's not significant while it's just synthetic timing test. Regex inside it's just a state machine. Every time it's called it does exactly same operation. Your difference is not about Regex, but about .NET execution nature.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you are using `RegexOptions.Compiled`, please refer to the regex performance tips from [David Gutierrez's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/11/12/256783.aspx):

> In this case, we **first do the work to parse into opcodes**.  Then we also **do more work to turn those opcodes into actual IL using `Reflection.Emit`**. As you can imagine, ***this mode trades increased startup time for quicker runtime***: in practice, compilation takes about an order of magnitude longer to startup, but yields 30% better runtime performance.  There are **even more costs for compilation that should mentioned**, however.  Emitting IL with `Reflection.Emit` loads a lot of code and uses a lot of memory, and that's not memory that you'll ever get back... The bottom line is that you should only use this mode for a finite set of expressions which you know will be used repeatedly.

That means that running the regex match first time, this additional work ("compile time") is performed, and all subsequent times the regex is executed without that preparation.

However, beginning with .NET 2.0, the [behavior of caching has modified a bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f(v=vs.110).aspx):

> In the .NET Framework 2.0, **only regular expressions used in static method calls are cached**. By default, ***the last 15 regular expressions are cached***, although the size of the cache can be adjusted by setting the value of the [CacheSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.cachesize(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Try running the first IsMatch outside the loop. Add `var firstCheck = regex.IsMatch(message);`. In my test, the results are 35, 30, 30 (ticks).

Answer (score 1):

It's common situation for any managed platform Java/.NET - while they do some things behind the scene GC for example, and while we use concurent OS-es (win, linux) such tests are not exactly measeare. You think that you are testing regex itself - but you test .NET, Windows, and your antivirus at same time too.

One valid  way is execute regex for 50-1000 times, summarize time and eval average duration. For example rewrite:

```
 sw.Start();
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {  
     regex.IsMatch(message);
 }
 sw.Stop();
  Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
```

and i think you result will be much stable. But you still will get some range of values for ex [15ms .. 18ms], and that is described upper.

If you want really perfect measure (but your question... sory man... show that you not really want it). You require to use PROFILER that will give you exactly measure of time inside regex call without anything except it.

Comment: Another possibility of varing is that regular expressions can be *compiled*, so include *warming up* (1-3 calls `regex.IsMatch(message);`) before time measuring.

Comment: Author said that regex was compiled

Comment: @DmitryBychenko The first three runs are slightly longer than the rest, but some running times are still a bit higher even in the later calls. And yes, it is compiled.